# APINotAllowedError on GET /users/user-id

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Been running into this error as of late, when we try looking up users via the API. Googling around a bit, it sounds like in the past, this was due to the user account being private, but there's nothing in the documentation that says a simple get of the username, etc, isn't allowed, and I do believe it used to work.

Was this an intentional change on their part, or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It is still due to account being private. There is a lot of undocumented behavior in instagram API. Intentional decision or lousy API?